# Sum a column and get the first row in Transact Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table MOUVEMENTS which has 3 columns :

```
ID     IDREF     NUMBER
1      1         5
2      1         3
3      1         4
4      1         2
5      2         1
```

I'd like to fetch the rows of this table with that constraints :

- IDREF = 1
- Ordered by ID ASC
- and the X first SUM of NUMBER (by IDREF)

I imagine that we will first calculate the SUM. And then we will restrict with that column

```
ID     IDREF     NUMBER   SUM
1      1         5        5
2      1         3        8
3      1         4        12
4      1         2        2
5      2         1        1
```

In this case, if we want to have 11, we will take the two first column + the third and we will change the number to have a coherent value.

So the result awaited :

```
ID     IDREF     NUMBER   SUM
1      1         5        5
2      1         3        8
3      1         3        11
```

Please note the change in the third line on the NUMBER and SUM column.

Do you know how to achieve that ?

This query should work from sql 2000 to 2008 R2

Comment: what version of sql server?

Comment: well I made a mistake this query must be compliant from 2000 to 2008 R2

Comment: Can you please explain the third requirement for selecting rows. Also give example of the result set similar to the table data you have given.

Comment: @Tobsey I updated the question with the result awaited. the sum of the number must be 4

Comment: no I would make the sum and if I need 4. I will need also the 2 first column but in number there will be 3 and then 1

Comment: I think it would be easy to understand if you could show data and results using x,y,z.

Comment: I changed my question. I think it is more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a solution here which uses a view: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ebb01/15

The view contains a running total column for each IDRef:

```
CREATE VIEW MouvementsRunningTotals
AS
  SELECT
    A.ID,
    A.IDRef,
    MAX(A.Number) Number,
    SUM (B.Number) RunningTotal
  FROM
    Mouvements A
    LEFT JOIN Mouvements B ON A.ID >= B.ID AND A.IDRef = B.IDRef
  GROUP BY
    A.ID,
    A.IDRef
```

If you can't create a view then you could create this as a temporary table in tsql.

Then the query is a self join on that view, in order to determine which is the last row to be include based on the Number you pass in. Then a `CASE` statement ensures the correct value for the last row:

```
DECLARE @total int
DECLARE @idRef int
SELECT @total = 4
SELECT @idRef = 1

SELECT 
  A.ID,
  A.IDRef,
  CASE 
    WHEN A.RunningTotal <= @total THEN A.Number
    ELSE  @total - B.RunningTotal
  END Number
FROM 
  MouvementsRunningTotals A
  LEFT JOIN MouvementsRunningTotals B ON 
            A.IDRef = B.IDRef 
            AND A.RunningTotal - A.Number = B.RunningTotal
WHERE
  A.IDRef = @IDRef
AND (A.RunningTotal <= @total
OR (A.RunningTotal > @total AND B.RunningTotal < @total))
```

You can add more data in the Build Schema box and change the Number in the @total parameter in the Query box to test it.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, (select top 1 number from mouvements) as number, idref 
from mouvements where idref=1 order by id asc
```

Comment: sorry it isn't so simple ;)

Comment: @P.Sohm If you explain what you want to achieve in detail I can give you a solution in seconds.

Comment: sorry that does not complain. I will update my question to be more explicit

Comment: at least, I change my question. it should be more readable. Sorry it was hard to explain